# Document.getElementsbyid().value issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use:

`documents.getElemtsById("id).value = new value`

However, I get the error:

> Property Value does not exist on HTML element.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: my input element is <TextField> whose value needs to turn to upper case on click of a button.
the value does change to upper case and is displayed in the textfield, but when i click on the text firld again it changes back to the original version. I am unsure where i am going wrong. For example, original text="test"
on clicking button, new text="TEST"
But when i click on the text area again it changes to "test" i want to keep the new text and be able to add new words. I am trying to achieve a rich text editor like functionality from scratch

Answer (score 1):

Core of the issue here is that `document.getElementById("id")` returns general `HTMLElement` type - which is correct.

Returned `HTMLElement` can be `div`, `input`, `span`, etc... And not all of them have `value` propertly.

In your case, you are probably trying to assign `value` of an `<input />` element, so you need to cast:

```js
const myInputElement = document.getElementById("id") as HTMLInputElement;
myInputElement.value = "1";
```

In this case, type checker will also ensure that `value` you want to assign is of type `string`, which is correct behavior.

Comment: HI, this seems to work, but i am  facing an issue. my input element is <TextField> whose value needs to turn to upper case on clickink an button.
the value does change to upper case and is displayed in the textfield, but when i click on the text firld again it changes back to the original version. I am unsure where i am going wrong. For example, original text="test"
on clicking button, new text="TEST"

Comment: I think it's better to ask that as a separate question, adding a minimal, but reproducible code example to illustrate the problem. You probably have multiple event handlers in the your code.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` allows you to pass in a generic type for better typesafety

```js
document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>("#id")!.value = ""
```

We can use the non null assertion operator ("!") if the element is accessible for sure.